# Use STL find_if() to find a specific object in a Vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to find a certain object in a Vector of object pointers.
Lets say these are my classes.

```
// Class.h
class Class{
public:
    int x;
    Class(int xx);
    bool operator==(const Class &other) const;
    bool operator<(const Class &other) const;
};

// Class.cpp
#include "Class.h"
Class::Class(int xx){
    x = xx;
}

bool Class::operator==(const Class &other) const {
    return (this->x == other.x);
}

bool Class::operator<(const Class &other) const {
    return (this->x < other.x);
}

// Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Class.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<Class*> set;
    Class *c1 = new Class(55);
    Class *c2 = new Class(34);
    Class *c3 = new Class(67);
    set.push_back(c31);
    set.push_back(c32);
    set.push_back(c33);

    Class *c4 = new Class(34);
}
```

Lets say that for my purposes, 2 objects of class are equal if their 'x' values are the same. So in the above code, i'd like to use a predicate in the STL find_if() method to be able to 'find' c4 in the vector.

I can't seem to get a predicate to work. I'm basing my find predicate on the predicate I wrote for sorting.

```
struct less{
    bool operator()(Class *c1, Class *c2){return  *c1 < *c2;}   
};
sort(set.begin(), set.end(), less());
```

This sorting predicate works fine. So I adapted it to use for finding

```
struct eq{
    bool operator()(Class *c1, Class *c2){return  *c1 == *c2;}  
};
```

Why won't this predicate work?
What is the better way of writing a predicate for this?

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried to use that predicate? Did it compile? Did it produce results other than what you expected?

Comment: At first glance, your code looks ok to me, but why are you storing pointers in the vector? It's usually simpler, more efficient and safer to just store the objects themselves.

Comment: What happens if you hack your predicate to print out `c1->x` and `c2->x`?

Comment: Also, you say `find` in the title, but `find_if` in the question text (and you don't show how you call either), so which is it, and how do you call it?

Comment: The STL does not use namespace `std`.

Comment: @Rob - find_if didn't compile with my predicate

Comment: @Tomalak - i know ... i just pasted some of my code .. i was using std namespace for some other stuff

Comment: @jalf not always true.. if your objects are pretty huge and you do a lot of copy operations on those vectors, storing pointers would be more performant. But yeah it works fine for most cases.

Comment: @Pigol: You may not I said "usually", not "always". ;) Also, in that case, smart pointers are often preferable. And of course, on a C++0x compiler supporting move semantics, even that often isn't necessary

Comment: @Andrei: STL `find_if` is not in `std::` either. The C++ Standard Library `find_if`, however, is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find_if` takes a unary predicate, NOT a binary predicate.

```
struct eq{
    eq(const Class* compare_to) : compare_to_(compare_to) { }
    bool operator()(Class *c1) const {return  *c1 == *compare_to_;}  
private:
    const Class* compare_to_;
};
```

`std::find_if(set.begin(), set.end(), eq(c4));`