# How to search through vector of object pointers C++

Tags: c++, vector, predicate, stl-algorithm

I am trying to search through a vector of object pointers. My code will prompt the user to input a first name or last name and print out the Profile object information.

**i.e. The user will read in a text file like the one below.**

```
Homer Simpson hs742 donut123!
Bart Simpson bs1 don't-have-a-cow-man 
Smith Wesson sw666 gunsgunsguns
```

and then when the user enters a first name or last name like Homer, the code will search the vector and print out:

```
Homer Simpson hs742 donut123!
```

My problem is trying to search and iterate through my `vector<Profile *>`. I tried searching the internet and found `find_if` but it is not working.

```
int main(){
    string fn;
    string ln;
    string usn;
    string pswrd;
    string name;

    vector <Profile *> pvector; //vector of object pointers
    ifstream myfile("file1.txt");

       if(myfile.is_open())
        {
            while (myfile >> fn >>ln >>usn>>pswrd)
            {
                Profile * prf;
                prf = new Profile(fn, ln, usn, pswrd);
                pvector.push_back(prf);
            }
        } else cout <<"Error opening file" <<endl;
        myfile.close();


    do {
        cout<<"Enter name to search for: ";
        cin>>name;
        //search vector
        vector<Profile *>::iterator it = find_if(pvector.begin(), pvector.end(), name);
        cout << "name: " << *it << '\n';

    } while (name != "end");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to have a lambda function comparing name with `Profile::name`.

Comment: Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914012/use-stl-find-if-to-find-a-specific-object-in-a-vector-of-object-pointers

Comment: While Galik's response is correct, for this task you may want a map rather than a vector.

Comment: Do you need a vector of pointers? It may be better to have a vector of objects. Currently your code leaks.

Comment: Once you get it working it may be worth getting a review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This answer contains the code for making your search work, and also a brief explanation on `find_if` and function predicates.

`find_if` from the STL requires a unary predicate as it's third argument. This [website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/?kw=find_if) has a very good explanation of find_if. In this case, unary predicate means it needs a boolean returning function as it's predicate.

`name` doesn't work because it is not a function.

This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394000/c-find-if-lambda) from stackOverflow has a good example of a lambda expression with `find_if`. And this [website](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) has an excellent explanation for making Lambda functions.

Below is an example of `find_if` with a Lambda function in place of 'name' in your 'find_if' which should work for you.

```
auto it = find_if(pvector.begin(), pvector.end(), [=](const Profile *P){
        return P->fName == name || P->lName == name;
});
```

As Loki pointed out, be sure to delete the dynamically allocated Profiles, because your code has a memory leak. Anytime you use the 'new' keyword, you must use 'delete' so there isn't a memory leak. This is accomplish in your case by:

```
for (auto &x: pvector) delete (*x);
```

Because I didn't see your original `Profile` struct, I recreated the best approximation I could so I could test it. Here I my struct.

```
struct Profile{
    string fName;
    string lName;
    string userName;
    string pWord;

    Profile(string fn, string ln, string usn, string pw)
            : fName(fn), lName(ln), userName(usn), pWord(pw)
    {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks that really helps, I have one question. What is the fName and lName variables. Where do they come from? P->fName == name || P->lName == name;

Comment: I re-created an approximation to your struct/class so I could make it testable. I'll edit the answer so you can see it. This way I can compare the values of `first_name` and `last_name` against `name` as the struct is passed to the Lambda.